# Hide and show the Toolbar according to the scrolling

Tags: codenameone

*This question is referring to Codename One only.*

I need to make the Toolbar of a Codename One Form moving as shown in this video:
https://www.informatica-libera.net/videoLavoro/hideShowToolbarOnScrolling.mp4

As you can see, the scroll up causes the Toolbar to gradually disappear, while the scroll down causes the Toolbar to gradually reappear.

A solution like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55856590 is not applicable because I don't need to change the UIID of the Toolbar, but I need to move the Toolbar up and down during the scroll, to get the same effect shown in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach we took in the whatsapp clone application for toolbar as that's the exact behavior of whatsapp. There is more to it but this block contains most of the logic that implements this:

```
private void bindFolding(Container titleArea, int titleHeight, 
        Container... scrollables) {
    addPointerReleasedListener(e -> {
        if(titleArea.getHeight() != titleHeight && 
                    titleArea.getHeight() != 0) {
            if(titleHeight - titleArea.getHeight() > titleHeight / 2) {
                titleArea.setPreferredSize(null);
            } else {
                titleArea.setPreferredH(0);
            }
            titleArea.getParent().animateLayout(100);
        }
    });
    for(Container c : scrollables) {
        c.addScrollListener((scrollX, scrollY, oldscrollX,
            oldscrollY) -> {
            // special case for tensile drag
            if(scrollY <= 10) {
                titleArea.setPreferredSize(null);
                return;
            }
            int diff = oldscrollY - scrollY;
            if(diff > 0) {
                if(titleArea.getHeight() < titleHeight) {
                    titleArea.setPreferredH(Math.min(titleHeight, 
                        titleArea.getPreferredH() + diff));
                    titleArea.setHeight(titleArea.getPreferredH());
                    titleArea.getParent().revalidate();
                }
            } else {
                if(diff < 0) {
                    if(titleArea.getHeight() > 0) {
                        titleArea.setPreferredH(Math.max(0, 
                            titleArea.getPreferredH() + diff));
                        titleArea.setHeight(titleArea.getPreferredH());
                        titleArea.getParent().revalidate();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very useful, I adapted it to my use case. If there isn't enough scrollable content, the code you suggested has a weird effect, while it works fine if the scrollable content is enough. Moreover, the tensile drag and the status bar create issues on special circumstances. That's why I created this modified version of your code that has additional checks and prevents weird effects in special circumstances, maybe it can be useful: https://gist.github.com/jsfan3/5f6e896a944660c53cc2cd46dc0642fd

Comment: I think there are workarounds for this in the full code, if you have the online course you can look there.

Comment: Yes, I have all your courses... but my attempts to compile the server of the Whatsapp clone always fail. All the errors are related to the database. I will better control this issue when I can modify my local mysql server without fear of damaging the apps I'm working on.

Comment: This just requires the client code so you can look at the frontend code there should be a bit of code in the constructor that sets up some initialization logic if I remember correctly.

Comment: Not trying to be annoying but setPreferredH is deprecated. Will it not be deprecated in the future? For now I will use it just trying to be on the safe side of things

Comment: @JAnton we're here to answer questions... Not a problem ;-) Preferred size related methods are deprecated because people often misuse them so we wanted a strong warning to developers there. When you point the mouse at the deprecation warning it should explain that in the deprecation docs. That method won't go away because there isn't a real alternative for it and if there will it would be a really long way off from now...