# codename one i want to make the toolbar hide on scrolling upwards

Tags: codenameone

I tried the solution provided at codenameone.com didn't work for me

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55860691/1277576

Comment: FYI you need to link to a specific problematic post and ideally include the code you used as there are a LOT of samples of this functionality on our site...